# Broken C# else if returning error page

Tags: c#, linq, if-statement

I am trying to work with if else statements for different things. I need one that pulls the value of a dropdown list to determine what the calculation will be, another that pulls the value of a check box and assigns a calculation, another for input validation for if the number exceeds 32, and the last to give me a value determined by the amount (up to 32) entered into the textbox. I think i've gotten the checkbox statement corrected (guideFee), and the input validation and the one that goes with it seem to be correct already, but I am having trouble assigning the constant decimal values to the dropdown list values and I don't understand why. I have the basetourRate = Convert.ToDecimal(riverTour) and the if statement that follows, but when I run the program I get an error page. I have pasted the whole code. If anyone could help me out i'd greatly appreciate it, thank you!

```
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void butCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e )
    {
        //1. Declare Variables
        decimal totalBaseTourFee;
        decimal totalGuideFee;
        decimal totalWeekendSurcharge;
        decimal subtotal;
        decimal salesTaxCharge;
        decimal totalCharge;
        decimal baseTourRate;         
        decimal guideFee = 0m;
        bool isGuidedTour;
        int numberOfRafters;
        int numberOfRaftsNeeded; 
        string riverTour;
        string timeOfWeek;
        string displayTotalBaseTourFee;
        string displayNumberOfRaftsNeeded;
        string displayTotalGuideFee;
        string displayTotalWeekendSurcharge;
        string displaySubtotal;
        string displaySalesTaxCharge;
        string displayTotalCharge;

        const decimal FRENCH_BROAD = 40m;
        const decimal NANTAHALA = 30m;
        const decimal TUCK = 20m;
        const decimal WEEKEND_SURCHARGE = 10M;
        const decimal GUIDE_FEE = 35M;
        const decimal SALES_TAX_RATE = .07M;

        //2. Get Values
        numberOfRafters = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfRafters.Text);
        riverTour = ddlTour.SelectedValue;
        isGuidedTour = chkGuided.Checked;
        timeOfWeek = rblDay.SelectedValue;

        Trace.Warn("numberOfRafters = " + numberOfRafters);
        Trace.Warn(("isGuidedTour = " + isGuidedTour));
        Trace.Warn("riverTour = " + riverTour);
        Trace.Warn("timeOfWeek = " + timeOfWeek);

        //Input Validation

        if (numberOfRafters > 32)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sorry, we can't handle this large of a group!");
            return;
        }
        //3. Do Calculations
        baseTourRate = Convert.ToDecimal(riverTour);

        if (riverTour == "FB")
        {
            baseTourRate = FRENCH_BROAD; 
        }
        else if (riverTour == "NH")
        {
            baseTourRate = NANTAHALA;
        }
        else if (riverTour == "TK")
        {
            baseTourRate = TUCK;
        }



        if (isGuidedTour == true)
        {
             guideFee = GUIDE_FEE;
        }
        else if (!isGuidedTour == false)
        {
            guideFee = 0;
        }

        totalBaseTourFee = numberOfRafters * baseTourRate;
        numberOfRaftsNeeded = numberOfRafters;

        if (numberOfRafters <= 8)
        {
            numberOfRaftsNeeded = 1;
        }
        else if (numberOfRafters <= 16)
        {
            numberOfRaftsNeeded = 3;
        }
        else if (numberOfRafters <= 24)
        {
            numberOfRaftsNeeded = 3;
        }
        else if (numberOfRafters <=32)
        {
            numberOfRaftsNeeded = 4;
        }

        totalGuideFee = numberOfRaftsNeeded * guideFee;
        totalWeekendSurcharge = numberOfRafters * WEEKEND_SURCHARGE;
        subtotal = totalBaseTourFee + totalGuideFee + totalWeekendSurcharge;
        salesTaxCharge = subtotal * SALES_TAX_RATE;
        totalCharge = subtotal + salesTaxCharge;

        //4. Display Results
        displayTotalBaseTourFee = totalBaseTourFee.ToString("C") + "<br>";
        displayNumberOfRaftsNeeded = numberOfRaftsNeeded.ToString("C") + "<br>";
        displayTotalGuideFee = totalGuideFee.ToString("C") + "<br>";
        displayTotalWeekendSurcharge = totalWeekendSurcharge.ToString("C") + "<br>";
        displaySubtotal = subtotal.ToString("C") + "<br>";
        displaySalesTaxCharge = salesTaxCharge.ToString("C") + "<br>";
        displayTotalCharge = totalCharge.ToString("C") + "<br>";

        lblTotalBaseTourFee.Text = displayTotalBaseTourFee;
        lblNumberOfRafts.Text = displayNumberOfRaftsNeeded;
        lblTotalGuideFee.Text = displayTotalGuideFee;
        lblTotalWeekendSurcharge.Text = displayTotalWeekendSurcharge;
        lblSubtotal.Text = displaySubtotal;
        lblSalesTaxCharge.Text = displaySalesTaxCharge;
        lblTotalCharge.Text = displayTotalCharge;
    }

    protected void butClear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clear TextBox and Label
        txtNumberOfRafters.Text = "";
        lblTotalBaseTourFee.Text = "";
        lblNumberOfRafts.Text = "";
        lblTotalGuideFee.Text = "";
        lblTotalWeekendSurcharge.Text = "";
        lblSubtotal.Text = "";
        lblSalesTaxCharge.Text = "";
        lblTotalCharge.Text = "";

        ddlTour.SelectedIndex = -1;
        rblDay.SelectedIndex = -1;

        chkGuided.Checked = false;

        //Set focus back to name textbox
        txtNumberOfRafters.Focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: That is quite a bit of code.  Try to distill it down to a minimal reproducible code for the best chances of a good answer.

Comment: `I get an error page` and the error is....?

Comment: K.I.S.S.!!! Bowled code doesn't means any information... Try to split the code, simplifying the methods, then you can focus in your main problem

Comment: @EricJ. I am entirely new to all this so I have no idea what i'm doing with c# just yet, but you aren't the first person to tell me that so I know now that the other person wasn't just being picky. I appreciate you baring with me! I know this wasn't the easiest thing to read, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The one thing that sticks out to me is the Convert.ToDecimal(...) call.

```
        baseTourRate = Convert.ToDecimal(riverTour);

        if (riverTour == "FB")
        {
            baseTourRate = FRENCH_BROAD; 
        }
        else if (riverTour == "NH")
        {
            baseTourRate = NANTAHALA;
        }
        else if (riverTour == "TK")
        {
            baseTourRate = TUCK;
        }
```

You are attempting to convert a string to a decimal but then you are comparing that string to a string. My guess is that riverTour is not really a decimal and therefore you are getting an exception. Basically, the logic does not make sense. Convert.ToDecimal will throw an exception if it is not a valid decimal. Therefore, riverTour cannot contain a convertible value to decimal and a comparable value to FB/NH/TK. What exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you are trying to convert to decimal if it is valid and then check those 3 cases if it is not then you should look into decimal.TryParse(string, out decimal) https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9zbda557(v=vs.110).aspx. This might help you achieve what you are trying to do.

If the input is always numeric, then you should consider using NumericUpDown. Or, at the very least, use TryParse methods so you can tell if the input is valid or invalid.

```
numberOfRafters = Convert.ToInt32(txtNumberOfRafters.Text);
```

Is also unsafe.

Comment: I took a look at the link you suggested and it helped, thank you so much! I know it wasn't the easiest thing to read, but i'm new to all this so I appreciate you baring with me!

Comment: @A.Hull You could mark the answer as accepted. And next time please try to ask a more succinct and pointed question. In the process of slimming it down people tend to find the solution themselves.